# How does Typescript --allowJs work?

Tags: typescript

I have read:

- [TypeScript Roadmap 1.8](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#18)
- [JavaScript in TypeScript
  compilations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4792)
- [Compilation of Js
  Files](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5471)
- [Announcing TypeScript 1.8
  Beta](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/01/28/announcing-typescript-1-8-beta/)

but I still don't get how it works and what it is good for. Could
   someone please explain what it is and when I would want to use it?

Comment: [Bundling and transpilation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5471)...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [Clay Allsopp on Medium](https://medium.com/@clayallsopp/incrementally-migrating-javascript-to-typescript-565020e49c88):

> allowJs is the option newly available in 1.8. The TypeScript compiler
>   will run a quick sanity check on .js files for syntax errors but
>   otherwise passes them straight through to the output directory.

This is useful when migrating a JavaScript project to TypeScript, that way you don't have to migrate everything at once but instead start writing new code in TypeScript and/or migrate each file one by one. You can find more information about migration from JavaScript to Typescript on the official site for TypeScript that has a tutorial called "[Migrating from JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html)".