# Javascript: Unexpected token { - occurs when try to import custom class in typescript file into javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, command-line-interface

I am writing simple CLI scripts for react-native project. But I am not available to import class from typescript to javascript. It throw me following error.

> import { TestResult } from './src/lib/modules/test-result';
>    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {...

**package.json**

```
...
"script": {
...
"formular:convert": "node convertor.js"
...
}
...
```

**convertor.js**

```
import {TestResult} from './src/lib/models/test-result';
...
```

**test-result.ts**

```
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';

import { Exception } from '../../errors';
import { OilTypes, RawMaterialTypes } from '../oils';

import { CalculatedResult } from './calculated-result';
import { DeviceSettings } from './device-settings';
import { DeviceStatus } from './device-status';
import { DisplayedResult } from './displayed-result';
import { Measurement } from './measurement';
import { PhoneInfo } from './phone-info';
import { PrimaryCompound } from './primary-compound';

export class TestResult {
    constructor(
        public id: string = uuid(),
        public createdAt: Date = new Date(),
        public updatedAt: Date = new Date(),
        public errors: Exception[] = [],
        public alias: string = '',
        public analyteTemp: number = 75,
        public flowerWeight: number = 0,
        public hidden: boolean = false,
        public note: string = '',
        public oilType: OilTypes = OilTypes.OliveOil,
        public primaryCompound: PrimaryCompound = PrimaryCompound.UNDEFINED,
        public units: string = '',
        public user: string = '',
        public air310Meas: Measurement = new Measurement(),
        public air280Meas: Measurement = new Measurement(),
        public analyte310Meas: Measurement = new Measurement(),
        public analyte280Meas: Measurement = new Measurement(),
        public calculated: CalculatedResult = new CalculatedResult(),
        public displayed: DisplayedResult = new DisplayedResult(),
        public status: DeviceStatus = new DeviceStatus(),
        public settings: DeviceSettings = new DeviceSettings(),
        public phoneInfo: PhoneInfo = new PhoneInfo(),
        public rawMaterialType: RawMaterialTypes = RawMaterialTypes.Isolate,
    ) {
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        /* Basic Options */
        "target": "es5",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
        "module": "commonjs",                  /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
        // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
        "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
//        "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
        "jsx": "react",                 /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
                            /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
        "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
        "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */


        /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
        "strict": true,                        /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */

        /* Additional Checks */
        "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
        "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
        "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

        /* Module Resolution Options */
        "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
        "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
        "types": [                             /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
            "jest",
            "mocha",
            "detox"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
        "esModuleInterop": true,               /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */

        /* Experimental Options */
        "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
        "skipLibCheck": true,                  /* Skip type checking of declaration files. Requires TypeScript version 2.0 or later. */
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,/* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
        "resolveJsonModule": true              /* Include modules imported with '.json' extension. Requires TypeScript version 2.9 or later. */
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "babel.config.js",
        "metro.config.js",
        "jest.config.js"
    ]
}
```

I stuggled to find the solution, and found some answers here and there, but all of them doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to import TypeScript files into a JavaScript file?  That won't work; you'll need to transpile them.  What is "converter" supposed to do?

Comment: @Phix could you possibly let me know how I can transpile them? I am new to typescript.

Comment: Short answer- TypeScript is a superset of JS.  I would recommend doing some research online.

Answer (score 0):

You are running `node convertor.js` and `convertor.js` contains an `import` statement: `import {TestResult} from './src/lib/models/test-result';` This is not valid syntax in the version of node you are running, hence the error.

## Fix

You need to transpile the non-transpiled `.js` files with something like TypeScript (allowJs) or Babel.

Comment: I set the allowJs in tsconfig.json file. @basarat

Comment: @heltdev `allowJs` tells the TS compiler to allow JavaScript files. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089419/how-does-typescript-allowjs-work).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well while trying to use the react-native-device-info library with react-native 0.59. It turned out I was missing the @babel/core library in my package.json. After adding this module, the error went away and I was able to build the application.

Install using npm

```
npm i -s @babel/core
```

Install using yarn

```
yarn add @babel/core
```